# Iframe not displaying page in IE on button click

Tags: button, iframe, internet-explorer-11

I am facing this weird issue when working with iframes. 
I have a page(jsp) based on spring portlet framework which I want to render in an iframe. I made a dummy iframe and it was working perfectly fine in both IE(iE11) and Chrome when i was testing with my local server. However once the code got deployed to the dev server, the iframe renders the first page in IE, but does not render the next page on click of a button on that page. It is still working perfectly fine in chrome. I have no idea as to why that is happening.

Here is the code for my dummy iframe :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IFRAME DEMO</title>  
  </head>
  <body>  
  <a href="url" target="sampleFrame">Forgot Username</a>
  <a href="url" target="sampleFrame">Forgot Password</a>
  <iframe src="" width="82%" height="800" name="sampleFrame">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
  </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me figure out, if you click on a button inside the iframe, the action registered on the button click doesn't fire right? In IE on your server right?

Comment: The button does fire the event, but the page(jsp) which is supposed to come does not get displayed. However when i was testing this on my local server with IE, it was working.

Answer (score 1):

After reading some oldthreads, I figured out that I need to add the domain to the trusted site of IE and that solution worked. However this iframe will be exposed to the end user and I cannot expect every user to change this setting. Can we enforce it at server level somehow ?